# Find an item in a file in Bash

Tags: bash

```
cat "test1.txt" | while read delete
do
  grep -i "$delete" test2.txt > /home/user/nodes_deleted.txt
done
```

It's not working. Can anyone help. It's just printing all entries in test1.txt to nodes_deleted.txt.

Comment: research about `grep -f`

Comment: Provide a minimal input and expected output.

Comment: define "it is not working". Probably it has to do with you using `>` to redirect the output, which is removing the previous content on every loop.

Comment: contents is as follows:

Comment: text1.txt:   abc    bcd

Comment: text2.txt:  abc_no

Comment: expected output: abc_no and if it is not found in text2.txt it should return " no mach found for bcd"

Comment: @Sunny1985: Refer my solution below and let me know if it solves your problem and remove the newer question you asked now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your  expected input and output are quite vague, but since you have asked for a custom message `"no match found.."`, I am putting together a small shell script for this, with `file1` and `file2` contents as follows,

```
abc
bcd
```

and `file2` as

```
abc_no
```

And the `script.sh` contents as,

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line
do
   capture=$(grep -i "$line" file2 2>/dev/null)

   if [ ! -z "$capture" ]
   then
       echo "$capture"
   else
       echo "$line not found"
   fi

done <file1
```

Running it on the command line gives output

```
$ bash script.sh
abc_no
bcd not found
```

Comment: Hi Inian,It works as expected, But I need the entire line to be printed from file2, can you suggest the changes.

Comment: @Sunny1985: You want to search for `file1` content on `file2` or the other way around?

Comment: I want to search the content of file1 on file2 and print the content on file2 if  it matches.

Comment: @Sunny1985: Entire content of `file2` for each match? The requirement seems can be fine tuned

Comment: oopss. Inian, Your script not only displaying matched pattern , It also printing entire lines of file2. Can you check please.

Comment: @Sunny1985: Your statements are really vague. What is your expected output for your input files then? Is it not `abc_no
no match found for bcd`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I need the output as follows

Comment: abc_no    bcd not found

Comment: and if any other words present in file2, no need to present in output.

Comment: Refer my update, it outputs `abc_no bcd not found` as you needed.

Comment: yes, and it also displaying the unmatched pattern in file2. Which is not needed.

Comment: @Sunny1985: what you are you talking man? You stated an expected output and I provided it and you still saying it is not needed?

Comment: sorry for confusion Inian, Please check changes I've made.

Comment: Am not sure if you are running the commands as I passed or something else. I am explaining clearly again. My file1 contents are `abc
bcd` file2 contents are `abc_no
def
ghi
jkl` and the output am getting out of script is `abc_no
no match found for bcd` only. I will leave it to you to debug further

Comment: @Sunny1985: How about an upvote too? for all the efforts?